# android - maven unable to create project from archetype

Tags: android, maven

I've installed the eclipse helios, the android sdk(put that in my path), the android m2e plugin for eclipse, and Maven 3.0.3(also in my path). I can create normal android projects just fine. I'm attempting to create a project using Maven through eclipse and i select the "de.akquinet.android.archetypes" android-quickstart Archetype and i get the following error every time.

> 'Creating android-quickstart' has encountered a problem.
>
> Unable to create proejct from archetype
>   [de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart:1.0.8 -> ]
>
> Unable to create project from archetype
>   [de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart:1.0.8 -> ] The
>   desired archetype does not exist
>   (de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart:1.0.8)

What step am i missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all install latest version of Maven (3.1.x).

After that, in Eclipse do the following:

`New` -> `Maven Project` -> (next) -> `Add Archetype` and enter:

```
Archetype Group Id: de.akquinet.android.archetypes
Archetype Artifact Id: android-quickstart
Archetype Version: 1.1.0
```

Then enter your project informations (groupId, artifactId, package) and finish the wizard.

If this shouldn't work try creating the project with you command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.0 \
  -DgroupId=your.company \
  -DartifactId=my-android-application
```

And then import it in Eclipse.

Please remember that `m2eclipse` is not enough but you need also `m2e-android`: http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above mentioned steps to create a new android maven project...yet I was getting the below error:

```
Creating android-quickstart' has encountered a problem. 
Unable to create proejct from archetype [de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-             quickstart:1.0.10 -> ]
Unable to create project from archetype [de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart:1.0.10 -> ] The desired archetype does not exist         (de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart:1.0.10)
```

However when I deleted the folder `de\akquinet\android\archetypes\android-quickstart\1.0.10\` from my maven repo it worked for me.

This solution was posted on the blog below:
http://datastub.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/android-maven-unable-to-create-project.html

Hope it helps.